# How to select a column based on value of another in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe, where some column `special_column` contains values like `one`, `two`. My dataframe also has columns `one_processed` and `two_processed`.

I would like to add a new column `my_new_column` which values are taken from other columns from my dataframe, based on processed values from `special_column`. For example, if `special_column == one` I would like `my_new_column` to be set to `one_processed`.

I tried `.withColumn("my_new_column", F.col(F.concat(F.col("special_column"), F.lit("_processed"))))`, but Spark complains that i cannot parametrize `F.col` with a column.

How could I get the string value of the concatenation, so that I can select the desired column?

Answer (score 2):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col, lit, concat_ws
```

```
sdf.withColumn("my_new_column", when(col("special_column")=="one", col("one_processed"
).otherwise(concat_ws("_", col("special_column"), lit("processed"))
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way in your case would be just a simple `when/oterwise` like:

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2, "one"), (1,2,"two")], ["one_processed", "two_processed", "special_column"]) 
>>> df.withColumn("my_new_column", F.when(F.col("special_column") == "one", F.col("one_processed")).otherwise(F.col("two_processed"))).show()
+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
|one_processed|two_processed|special_column|my_new_column|
+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
|            1|            2|           one|            1|
|            1|            2|           two|            2|
+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
```

As far as I know there is no way to get a column value by name, as execution plan would depend on the data.

Comment: @Maruisz how would you do this for multiple special_column values. If not natively is there a way to get it through UDFs?

Comment: Just use when multiple times, like `F.when(condition1, value1).otherwise(F.when(condition2, value2).otherwise(value3))`